# How to map a 0-argument JavaScript function in PureScript FFI

Tags: ffi, purescript

I am trying to import the following JavaScript function into PureScript using the FFI:

```
function getGreeting() {
  return "Hi, welcome to the show."
}
```

but I am not sure what the type should be.  The closest I get to is something like:

```
foreign import getGreeting :: Unit -> String
```

I do want `getGreeting` to stay a function, and not convert it to a constant.

Is there a better way to write the type?  I tried to see what PureScript does if I define a dummy function in PureScript itself with that type of signature:

```
var getGreeting = function (v) {
  return "Hi, welcome to the show.";
};
```

Is there a way to get rid of that `v` parameter that is not being used?

TIA

Comment: "I do want getGreeting to stay a function, and not convert it to a constant" I think that this function is a constant. Why you want to have such a function?

Comment: If you are using some kind of side effect or you are relying on some external state to produce or fetch this value, I think that you can set this function type to `getGreeting :: forall eff. Eff (SOME_EFFECT | eff) String` .

Comment: @paluh I do not want to change `getGreeting` because it is not my source code and should be considered unchangeable for now :)  Also there are no side effects, so having the `Eff` type is undesirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Unit -> String` is a perfectly good type for that, or perhaps `forall a. a -> String`. The latter type may seem too permissive, but we know for sure that the `a` is unused thanks to parametricity, so that the function still must be constant.

Answer (score 3):

There is really useful package`purescript-functions` which can be helpful in such a situation and if you really have to call this function from Purescript as it is (because I think that it `IS` really just a constant) you can try:

```hs
module Main where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
import Data.Function.Uncurried (Fn0, runFn0)

foreign import getString ∷ Fn0 String

main :: forall e. Eff (console :: CONSOLE | e) Unit
main = do
  log (runFn0 getString)
```

I've created this simple javascript module so this example can be tested:

```
/* global exports */
"use strict";

// module Main

exports.getString = function() {
  return "my constant string ;-)";
};
```

Comment: thanks paluh.  It is good to know about `Data.Function.Uncurried`.  I decided to go with the answer from gb because for something so simple, giving the type `Unit -> String` seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Cool! `Data.Function.Uncurried` can be especially useful when you have functions WITH (multiple) arguments on the javascript side and don't want to wrap them to write FFI bindings ;-)